# Pytorch: Batch size is missing in data after torch.utils.random_split() is used on dataloader.dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I used random_split() to divide my data into train and test and I observed that if random split is done after the dataloader is created, batch size is missing when getting a batch of data from the dataloader.

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
from torch.utils.data import random_split

# Normalize the data
transform_image = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.Resize((240, 320)),
  transforms.ToTensor(),
  transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

data = '/data/imgs/train'

def load_dataset():
  data_path = data
  main_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
    root = data_path,
    transform = transform_image
  )

  loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset = main_dataset,
    batch_size= 64,
    num_workers = 0,
    shuffle= True
  )

  # Dataset has 22424 data points
  trainloader, testloader = random_split(loader.dataset, [21000, 1424])

  return trainloader, testloader

trainloader, testloader = load_dataset()
```

Now to get a single batch of images from the train and test loaders:

```
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
images.shape
# %%
len(trainloader)

# %%
images_test, labels_test = next(iter(testloader))
images_test.shape

# %%
len(testloader)
```

The output that I get is does not have the batch size for train or test batches. Teh output dims should be [batch x channel x H x W] but I get [channel x H x W].

Output:

[image]

But if I create the split from the dataset and then make two data loaders using the splits, I get the batchsize in the output.

```
def load_dataset():
    data_path = data
    main_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
      root = data_path,
      transform = transform_image
    )
    # Dataset has 22424 data points
    train_data, test_data = random_split(main_dataset, [21000, 1424])

    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
      dataset = train_data,
      batch_size= 64,
      num_workers = 0,
      shuffle= True
    )

    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
      dataset = test_data,
      batch_size= 64,
      num_workers= 0,
      shuffle= True
    )

    return trainloader, testloader

trainloader, testloader = load_dataset()
```

On running the same 4 commands to get a single train and test batch:

[image]

Is the first approach wrong? Although the length shows that the data has been split. So why do I not see the batch size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is wrong.

Only `DataLoader` instances return batches of items. The `Dataset` like instances don't.

When you call `make_split` you pass it `loader.dataset` which is just a reference to `main_dataset` (not a `DataLoader`). The result is that `trainloader` and `testloader` are `Dataset`s not `DataLoader`s. In fact you discard `loader` which is your only `DataLoader` when you return from `load_dataset`.

The second version is what you should do to get two separate `DataLoader`s.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting a dataset into two. This would give you 2 Datasets, which when iterated upon will return single image tensors of shape `channel, height, width`, i.e., `3,h,w`, and does not by default give you Dataloader around these datasets.
What you did next is actually the next right step, i.e., to create a Dataloader around each dataset. You define the batch size in the Dataloader and now iterating over a Dataloader will return tensors of shape `batch_size, channel, height, width`.

Even if you intend to feed the model batches of size one, you will have to have a batch size dimension in the tensor. For this, you can either use a Dataloader of `batchsize=1` or just add a dummy dimension at the start with `torch.unsqueeze(X, 0)` for an image `X` or `X.unsqueeze(0)`, making the tensor of shape `1,3,h,w`